# always run a script when running 'make' before compiling

Tags: makefile, automake

I'm using automake.

I'd like to have a script run each time I run 'make'.

This script does a git diff and generates an MD5 sum of the diff.

The hash is written as a #define in repos_version.h
e.g.:

```
#define REPOS_DIFF "-190886e9f895e80c42cf6b426dc85afd"
```

The script only rewrites this file if it doesn't exist or if the diff has is different to what is in repos_version.h already. But the script needs to be run for each make.

main.c includes repos_version.h and prints out the hash when the executable is run.

Here's Attempt 1 for Makefile.am

```
all: config.h
        @chmod +x gen_diff_hash.sh
        @./gen_diff_hash.sh
        $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) all-recursive
```

This work, but I get the following error

Makefile:1234: warning: overriding recipe for target `all'
Makefile:734: warning: ignoring old recipe for target`all'

Here's Attempt 2 for Makefile.am

```
all-local:
        @chmod +x gen_diff_hash.sh
        @./gen_diff_hash.sh

main.c: repos_version.h
```

However, this doesn't work, as all-local seems to be run too late. A second run of 'make' does get the desired result, but that's not a runner.

So neither are great.
Any ideas?
I've been reading through the automake hooks documentation, but I can't see anything that suits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could ensure the script is always run every time Make loads the Makefile, by executing it via `$(shell ./gen_diff_hash.sh)` and assigning it to a throwaway variable (or using it in some other construct like an ifeq or something).
Note, that [this is not POSIX](http://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=337), and on Make implementations other than GNU this isn't valid syntax. GNU Make 4.x supports using `VAR != ./gen_diff_hash.sh` as well, which is compatible with BSD Make at least.

But maybe it would be a better idea to create a `.PHONY: gendiff` target that runs the script, and make the header depend on this `gendiff`. The target would then be re-evaluated every time Make checks if repos_version.h is up-to-date, rather than every time Make is run at all.

Comment: I'm running the latest CentOS 7. I've the GNU make installed.

Am I having issues with the make that I have installed?


If I add the following:

    GENDIFF=$(shell ./gen_diff_hash.sh)

I get:

src/Makefile.am|215| warning: shell ./gen_diff_hash.sh: non-POSIX variable name
src/Makefile.am|215| (probably a GNU make extension)

Instead, If I add :

    .PHONY: gendiff
    gendiff:
            chmod +x gen_diff_hash.sh
            ./gen_diff_hash.sh

Nothing happens - the gendiff rule is not invoked.

Comment: That is because $(shell somecommand) is not POSIX, so if you use another implementation of Make (as opposed to the GNU one) it will break. You could use != for portability with BSD make... And you still need gendiff to be a dependency of repos_version.h

Comment: Unfortunately make 4.x doesn't seem to be an option for me at the moment. CentOS 7 comes with GNU Make 3.82.

Comment: If you do not care about your special script always running on non-GNU make, you can add a separate `GNUmakefile` alongside the top level `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in` and `Makefile`. Have the `GNUmakefile` start with `include Makefile`, then add the `$(shell ...)` stuff to the `GNUmakefile`. Then GNU make will do the magic, and non-GNU make will still run normal builds without running the `$(shell ...)` stuff. Non-minimal example available in my https://github.com/ndim/ndim-utils package.